# COMBINAR 3 ARRAYS EN PHP

Tags: php, array

Estoy intentando combinar 3 *arrays* en uno, pero solamente se puede hacer con dos *arrays*.

```
Array ( [0] => ITEM1 [1] => ITEM2 [2] => )  
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => )  
Array ( [0] => 50 [1] => 400 [2] => )
```

¿Cómo podría combinarlos para que el primer *array* fuera la `key` y poder sacarlos en una tabla de la siguiente forma?

```html
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>Concepto</td>
    <td>Unidades</td>
    <td>Precio</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ITEM 1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ITEM 2</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>400</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Si se trata de una representación de los datos (mostrarlos en una tabla), no veo qué sentido tiene perder esfuerzo y recursos en colocar el nombre de caaaada columna en caaada elemento del array. Tal práctica podría tener consecuencias de rendimiento, incluso desastrosas si el array es muy grande.

Una mejor solución sería:

1. Mantener un array independiente con lo que serían los nombres de las columnas de la tabla
2. Combinar los arrays con datos de una forma muy muy simple: ¡creando un nuevo array con todos ellos!  y luego hacer lo que se conoce como *transposición*, mediante la ayuda de `array_map`. Es decir, haremos que los diferentes elementos de cada array se vayan colocando en su columna respectiva.
3. Usaremos dos bucles `foreach` para construir nuestra tabla final.

El código sería este:

```
<?php
    $arrItems=array("Item1","Item2","Item n...");
    $arrUnidades=array(2,4,999);
    $arrPrecios=array(50,400,999);

    $arrColumns=array("Concepto","Unidades","Precio");

    $arrCombinado = array($arrItems,$arrUnidades,$arrPrecios);
    $arrOrdenado = transposeData($arrCombinado);
    $strHTML="<table>";
    $strHTML.="<thead>";
    $strHTML.="<tr>";
    #Columnas
    foreach ($arrColumns as $column){
        $strHTML.="<th>$column</th>";
    }
    $strHTML.="</tr>";

    #Filas
    foreach ($arrOrdenado as $v){
        $strHTML.="<tr>";
        foreach($v as $row){
            #Celdas
            $strHTML.="<td>$row</td>";
        }
        $strHTML.="</tr>";
    }
    $strHTML.="</table>";
    echo $strHTML;

    #Función para hacer la transposición
    function transposeData($data){
        return array_map(function (...$line){
            return $line;
        }, ...$data);
    }

?>
```

### Salida:

Vamos a obtener una tabla como esta:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <table class="table is-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Concepto</th>
                <th>Unidades</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item2</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Item n...</td>
                <td>999</td>
                <td>999</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

### Demostración

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN DEL CÓDIGO](http://rextester.com/PNEX34948)**</kbd> y hacer pruebas.

### Referencia

Puedes ver el artículo [*Transposition in PHP*](https://medium.com/@shaun_morrow/transposition-in-php-ef49dde5ca15) que ha servido de base para esta respuesta.

Comment: 2 años después, era lo que estaba buscando. Consulta, como podría, utilizando tu ejemplo, darle formato a cada uno de los <td>?, ya que necesito transformar a pdf y casi por obligación, debo darle formato a las columnas. saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ya he encontrado la solución, sería creando un array único con los tres arrays sin combinar:

```
foreach($arrayConcepto as $key => $valores)
 {
$files[$key]['concepto'] = $valores;
$files[$key]['unidades'] = $arrayUnidades[$key];
$files[$key]['precioGestion'] = $arrayPrecio[$key];
 }
```

Para sacar los valores simplemente:

```
   echo "<TABLE width='auto' border='1'>";
foreach ($files as $key2 => $value2) {

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $value2['concepto'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $value2['unidades'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $value2['precioGestion'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
   }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: no crees que son demasiado echo, es mucho codigo basura

Comment: si quieres combinar array podrias intentar con http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

**Array Simple**
Simplemente estructuralos como si fuera una base de datos e ir añadiendo linea por linea:

```
$datos[] =["Item1",2,50];
$datos[] = ["Item2",4,400];
```

O ambos de ellos del tiron:

```
 $datos = array(
      array("Item1",2,50),
      array("Item2",4,400) 
 );
```

Para luego escribir sus valores:

```
<tr>
  <th>Concepto</th>
  <th>Unidades</th>
  <th>Precio</th>
<tr>
<?php
  foreach($datos as $linea){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($linea as $dato){
      echo "<td>$dato</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  };

?>
```

---

**Array Asociativo** 
Si necesitas tener mas claro que es cada cosa en el array puedes darle nombre a cada index:

```
$datos = array(
   array("Concepto"=> "Item1", "Unidades"=>2, "Precio"=>50),
   array("Concepto"=> "Item2", "Unidades"=>4, "Precio"=>400)
)
```

Y para escribir:

```
<tr>
  <th>Concepto</th>
  <th>Unidades</th>
  <th>Precio</th>
<tr>
<?php
  foreach($datos as $linea){
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$linea["Concepto"]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$linea["Unidades"]."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$linea["Precio"]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";        
  };  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema está con la estructura de los arreglos. Deberías hacer un array asociativo que quedara de la siguiente manera:

```
$items = array(
    0 => array(
            'concepto' => 'ITEM 1',
            'unidades' => '2',
            'precio' => 50
        ),
    1 => array(
            'concepto' => 'ITEM 2',
            'unidades' => '4',
            'precio' => 400
        ),
);
```

Si no lo puedes armar con esta estructura nueva directamente, la forma más simple de lograrlo es pasando por foreach los tres arreglos;

```
foreach($miArray as $key => $value){
     $items[$key]['concepto'] = $value; //Para el primer Array
     $items[$key]['unidades'] = $value; //Para el segundo Array
     $items[$key]['precio'] = $value; //Para el tercer Array
}
```

y luego simplemente hacer una tabla de la siguiente manera:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Concepto</th>
            <th>Unidades</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($items as $item){?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $item['concepto'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['unidades'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['precio'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```